# ifelse doesn't work when applying filter on r

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Good I am trying to make a filter in R but the result is not as expected

```
x1 = c("PIB","PIB","PIB","PIB","PIB")
x2 = c("IBR","IBR","IBR","IBR","IBR")
coef_x1 = c(0.001,0.004,0.002,-0.099,-0.88)
coef_x2 = c(0.12,0.15,-0.99,-0.77,0.45)
Signo_x1 = c("+","+","+","+","+") 
Signo_x2 = c("+","+","+","+","+")

Table = data.frame(x1,x2,coef_x1,coef_x2,Signo_x1,Signo_x2)
```

that's the table I have

```
   x1  x2 coef_x1 coef_x2 Signo_x1 Signo_x2
1 PIB IBR   0.001    0.12        +        +
2 PIB IBR   0.004    0.15        +        +
3 PIB IBR   0.002   -0.99        +        +
4 PIB IBR  -0.099   -0.77        +        +
5 PIB IBR  -0.880    0.45        +        +
```

I need to perform a filter as follows

```
x1  x2 coef_x1 coef_x2 Signo_x1 Signo_x2
1 PIB IBR   0.001    0.12        +        +
2 PIB IBR   0.004    0.15        +        +
3 PIB IBR   0.002   -0.99        +        +
```

for the filter I am executing the following code:

**updated here**

```
 Table = ifelse(Table$Signo_x1 == "+",Table %>% dplyr::filter(Table$coef_x1 >= 0),Table %>% dplyr::filter(Table$coef_x1 <= 0))

[[1]]
[1] "PIB" "PIB" "PIB"

[[2]]
[1] "IBR" "IBR" "IBR"

[[3]]
[1] 0.001 0.004 0.002

[[4]]
[1]  0.12  0.15 -0.99

[[5]]
[1] "+" "+" "+"
```

anyone has the knowledge of how to convert it back as a dataframe or if the code i am using is not correct how could i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `&` to create the expression

```
library(dplyr)
Table %>%
    filter(Signo_x1 == "+" & coef_x1 >= 0)
```

-output

```
    x1  x2 coef_x1 coef_x2 Signo_x1 Signo_x2
1 PIB IBR   0.001    0.12        +        +
2 PIB IBR   0.004    0.15        +        +
3 PIB IBR   0.002   -0.99        +        +
```

---

Based on the comments, we may need `if/else`

```
Table %>%
    filter(if(any(Signo_x1 == "+" & coef_x1 >= 0)) 
       Signo_x1 == "+" & coef_x1 >= 0 else coef_x1 <=0)
  x1  x2 coef_x1 coef_x2 Signo_x1 Signo_x2
1 PIB IBR   0.001    0.12        +        +
2 PIB IBR   0.004    0.15        +        +
3 PIB IBR   0.002   -0.99        +        +
```

---

Or use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(Table, Signo_x1 == "+" & coef_x1 >= 0)
```

Comment: If not, it meets the condition Sign_x1 == "+" and it is Sign_x1 == "-", how can I make it another condition?

Comment: do an update to my question, in the opposite case, since if it does not meet a condition I need to execute another

Comment: @redondo are you looking for a solution or just only with `ifelse`(which doesn't work for these cases)

Comment: @redondo From your code, I have a question.  Are you looking for `OR` condition or just if not met altogether, do the second expression?

Comment: Correct if it is not completely fulfilled, make the second expression

Comment: @redondo then you need `if/else` or with `ifelse` have to wrap with `any`, but again that is not correct because `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same length